# mysql duplicate root users on mac pro

Tags: mysql, macos

I just set up mysql my Yosemite by following the directions here:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

I tried to set the password for root with the mysqladmin command. The result is that now I can log in mysql with the new password or no password. I think it's because one root user (root@localhost) has no password and the other root user has the new passwor.

Should I drop any root users here? I don't understand why 2 root users exist for both localhost and macbook-pro.local.

```
+------+-------------------+
| User | Host              |
+------+-------------------+
| root | 127.0.0.1         |
| root | ::1               |
|      | localhost         |
| root | localhost         |
|      | macbook-pro.local |
| root | macbook-pro.local |
+------+-------------------+
```

So I got another representation by add the password field:

```
mysql> select User,Host,password from mysql.user;
+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User | Host              | password                                  |
+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root | localhost         | *xxx |
| root | macbook-pro.local |                                           |
| root | 127.0.0.1         |                                           |
| root | ::1               |                                           |
|      | localhost         |                                           |
|      | macbook-pro.local |                                           |
+------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

So this made me understand that there are users with empty strings and I guess there's no duplicate after all. But then how do I NOT let users log in with just:
mysql -u root

Comment: just edit the privileges and set password for each user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set password for all `root` user:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'macbook-pro.local' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'::1' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
```

And if you don't want `any` user can log into your mysql without username and password, drop `any` user from the list:

```
DROP USER ''@'localhost'; 
DROP USER ''@'macbook-pro.local';
```

Note that `''` (blank) user is `any` user. If you don't set a password for them, any user(human, machine) can log into your mysql with `any` (means anything,any word,any phrase) as username without a password. 
But, your 2 blank users here is used by mysql (itself) during installation of mysql service, and it doesn't have granted access. If you have installed mysql service, you can safely drop them.
[see reference1](https://serverfault.com/questions/280711/) 
[see reference2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5620/)

Comment: It seems that after restarting the computer. Running the command: mysql -u root doesn't log me in anymore even if the passwords were still empty for the other root users. The command seems to only care about root@localhost.